# Where are Webmin's available modules stored?

Tags: webmin

The modules a *Webmin* user can see in the menu can be configured via the GUI under *Webmin/Webmin Users/Available Webmin modules*. Where are these settings stored? I need to restore them programmatically on a fresh Webmin installation - without accessing the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Available Webmin Modules* that are displayed in the menu are reflected in file */etc/webmin.acl*. It contains a space seperated list where modules are added when changing the settings via GUI.

In this case the configuration was made for the *root* user. The list therefore has the format

`root: moduleX, moduleY`.

It is likely that configurations for other users would be added in the same format, e.g.:

`userXYZ: moduleX, moduleY`

Restoring *webmin.acl* did the trick.